# Triangle is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive Error

Tags: graphics3d

The title pretty much says it all.  Even though this question is really simple, I have not been able to find an answer.  When I copy the example from the wolfram page,

```
Graphics3D[Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}]]
```

I get the error Triangle is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive.  Just for reference I am using Mathematica 9 (maybe this feature was not enabled till 10?)

[image]

Comment: [`Triangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Triangle.html) - says it was introduced in version 10.0

Comment: But `Graphics3D[Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}]]` works just fine

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that only exists in a later version of Mathematica than the one the OP is using.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have it, you can just define it:

```
Triangle[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, opts];
Triangle[pts : {_, _, _}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Polygon[pts, opts]
```

and at least for `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` it will work as expected.

[image: Mathematica graphics]